# Is it ok to post link of some resource as evidence in a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Note: the current allege duplicate question in fact cannot fully answer want I want to ask: the question is answering about question that meaningless,not understandable without external link, but I am also asking question that is meaningful,understandable without external link but still need external link as evidence, I will explain it later:

If I think letting user download the app can help to clarify (or speed up solving) the problem, is it ok to post the download link in the question at the following situation?

1. I want to ask question about game programming in my current project, the question need to elaborate the game mechanism, but it is impossible to show all my codes in the project to public (even I am willing to,who will research my wall of code?), I want to post my problematic code and also post my app to help identify the problem at the same time.
2. I want to ask about optimization, but someone doubt if I have optimization problem and I want to post my app to prove that I really need to optimize my app.
3. There may have some device specific problems that I cannot solve (e.g.:I have no such device) and need other users to help.
4. Some problems may only be appeared in app store version (e.g.:app icon,game center)
5. I want to mimic some elements (e.g.:visual effect,game mechanics) appeared in other app, but the app may have copyright and should not copy the content in that app
6. other possible situations...
7. A user don't believe my problem exists or think my question is non sense and have a close vote,I want to us external link as evidence to prove or support what I say.

Can I post download link of some app in the question?

The current allege duplicate question only answers 1,3,4,5 but cannot answer the question in situation 2.

Sometimes the question may be meaningful and understandable without external link, but users may still post close vote with some reasons: optimization is not necessary, the problem does not exist and I want an external link as support evidence to prove what I post, is that case external link still valid?

Comment: the question only answer the situation in 1,3,4,5 but not 2 (I updated the question and mentioned why it is not duplicate)

Comment: and also situation 7

Comment: Your situation 7 is also a non-issue. If it ever happens, it would be because you didn't include all relevant details in your question. Adding a link to an external resource does not help there. You need to prove that a _particular piece of code_ is slow, and you can't let other users download your app for that.

Comment: 7 is not restricted in optiumisation

Comment: Please give a concrete example because this all sounds quite hypothetical. Anyway my point stands, if users complain your problem is incomplete, you need to add **the problem** to your question. A link won't suffice.

Comment: now what I want to argue is if there is a question is complete,understandable and other users just complain or judge it is nonsense and I want to add some books or website stats to prove what I say (sometimes they may have copyright and I am not sure if it is suitable to copy that). If you can persuade me that such non reasonable judge will never occurs I do not oppose.

Comment: I can't tell you that such things never happen, as I can't speak for all users - just me. There are users who post such comments, and some of them may or may not know what they're talking about. If you do know that, and you feel their statements are irrelevant, you can safely ignore them. Anyway quoting and screenshots hardly ever invade copyright.

Answer (score 10):

No. It is your responsibility to narrow down the problem so much that it is a good fit for Stack Overflow.

As for your optimization case: optimization questions often are very poor questions. First and foremost because SO doesn't have all of your code *and* you can't expect SO to do the analysis for you.

Benchmarking and profiling are skills you need to obtain. *"My app runs slow, download it here and profile it for me"* is not a question you post on SO, it may be a question you ask a freelance developer if you don't know how to do it.

Questions like that are "too localized" (only helpful for OP, and only answerable after a lot of forth-and-back between OP and multiple commenters/answerers). Nowadays that's called "too broad" (too much discussion required or it'll only attract generic, long answers that won't really help with your specific problem).

If *you* can pinpoint the source of slowness, and you can post a minimal, complete, verifiable example, the question is more than welcome on SO.